# Did Firefox use to autocomplete websites in the address bar?

Tags: firefox, autocomplete, address-bar

In Chrome, when you type `face` into the address bar without hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it comes up with the URL of Facebook, `www.facebook.com`, and you can choose to enter that site.

I guess that was possible in Firefox too; at least I thought I was using it like that before. But now when I type `face`, for example, it doesn't come up with anything.

If you look at [this link on Mozilla](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-find-your-bookmarks-history-and-tabs#w_how-can-i-control-what-results-the-location-bar-shows-me), it only points out that it comes up with bookmarks or history results. I don't get it. Was it always like that or what?

I reset my Firefox and Firefox Sync but it didn't work. I am using Firefox 17.0.1.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/omnibar/

Comment: yes i do :) Thanks for that. I thought it is default function, i guess it's not for FF.

Comment: If you've visited the site previously, the latest version of Firefox will autofill the address.

Comment: Firefox has enabled autocomplete by default since some version that I didn't remember. That makes a little annoying each time I had to install firefox because I must disable it again